# How can I fix my code?

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL and I tried to use in sql and I got errors in our procedure this is our code:

```
proq sql;

select table sale1 as

SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         a.(*), MIN(b.ValueDate)
     FROM 
         CRM1 as a
     LEFT JOIN 
         work.final5 as b ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
                          AND a.CRMEventStartDate = b.ValueDate 
     WHERE 
         b.ATM IS NOT NULL 
     GROUP BY 
         a.CustomerID
     ORDER BY 
         b.ValueDate DESC);

quit;
```

There are two errors:

1. expecting one of the following : a name.*.
2. statement will be ignored

The errors are on the line

```
SELECT a.(*), MIN(b.ValueDate)
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Please consider changing the title of your question. Maybe 50% of all questions here are about fixing code, so that is like the worst title you could have chosen. Given the spelling mistake, the worst.

Comment: You can start by figuring out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: This doesn't look like **T-SQL / SQL Server** code - please tag with the **actual, real** RDBMS you're using !

Comment: It looks like SAS to me .. 'proc sql' is a SAS command.

Answer (score 0):

remove 2 `(` Brackets, and give your internal query alias `as temp` , your query should be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)

FROM (

SELECT a.*, MIN(b.ValueDate)

FROM CRM1 as a

LEFT JOIN work.final5 as b

ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID

AND a.CRMEventStartDate = b.ValueDate 

WHERE b.ATM IS NOT NULL 

GROUP BY a.CustomerID

ORDER BY b.ValueDate DESC) as temp;

quit;
```

Comment: it still the same error. i added "as temp" and nothing changing

Comment: there are two errors: 1. expecting one of the following : a name.*. 2. statement will be ignored

the errors with the line "SELECT a.(*), MIN(b.ValueDate)"

Comment: i changed my code as you suggested,now getting different error:

Comment: expecting one of the following !,!!&...affected code: ORDER BY b.ValueDate DESC

Comment: are you using SAS? It is best to do an ODBC passthrough if you are.  Please let me know and I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using SAS given the proc sql and work folders. I would recommend if you are extracting data from another database, stage the results of your first dataset and use data steps to merge the results.  If you are just combining results of your queries, it's much quicker to use data steps.

** Generic Syntax for passthrough **

```
proc sql;
   connect to odbc(datasrc="<<database name>>" QUERY_TIMEOUT=60);
   create table <<table you want to make>> as
   select * from connection to odbc
   (
   <<sql query here>>
   )
   ;
   disconnect from odbc;
quit;
```

** Proposed solution for you **

```
proc sql;
   create table sale1 as
     select
       a.*, min(b.ValueDate)
     from
       crm1 a
         left join work.final5 b on
                a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
            AND a.CRMEventStartDate = b.ValueDate 
     where
       b.atm is not null
     group by
       a.CustomerID;
quit;

proc sql;
   create table sale1tot as select count(*) from sale1;
quit;
```

You could also just use the MERGE statement in SAS like the following ...

```
data sale1;
   merge crm1(in=ina)
         work.final5(in=inb rename=(ValueDate=CRMEventStartDate));
   by CustomerID CRMEventStartDate;
   if ina and inb and inb.atm <> '';
run;
```